# How do I supply power to a detached garage

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage, meter

I added a detached garage and all the breaker spaces in my main panel are taken. How should do I go about connecting it? Can it be connected to the two lugs that are in the actual meter box at the bottom? It looks like to me an extra set of lugs for this purpose. I took a pic not sure how to add it the this message.

Comment: [Edit] the question and use the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box. Do not mess with the code it puts in or remove blank lines, etc. so that the picture will actually show up (as you can see *below* the edit box in the preview.) If it's a huge picture you might need to shrink it under 2 MB to load it.

Comment: What is the size of your main utility service? (May or may not be the same as the main breaker size) How much power do you want to have in the garage? Have you done any Load Calculations?

Comment: I know nothing about electrical how do I tell the size of the service and would like to run a 250 amp welder if needed and I know nothing about load calculations I will have two garage doors and 110 outlets